# CDF for Correlated Gumbel Distribution in Nested Logit simulation

Tags: distributions, logistic, simulation, gumbel-distribution

I am interested in estimating a nested logit model following McFadden (1978)'s formulation. It is simple to numerically verify the result in a standard situation with independently drawn error terms, but I do not know what the cdf is when error can be correlated.

To review, McFadden shows that the expectation of the maximum for options $i,..., N$ is:

$$E[ \max \{V_1 + \epsilon_1 , ... V_N + \epsilon_N  \}] = 0.5772 + \Big( \sum_{i=1}^N \exp[V_i]\Big)$$

Where $ \epsilon_i \sim EV(0,1)$.

This can be verified numerically - drawing plenty of $\epsilon_i$ values from an Extreme Value Type I (or Gumbel) distribution with a location value of 0 and scale parameter of 1.

In a nested logit model, the $\epsilon_i$ are correlated with parameters $\rho$. Say that that $\epsilon_1, ... , \epsilon_K $ are correlated this way. Then the expectation of maximum values is:
$$0.5772 + \ln\Big( (\sum_{k=1}^K \exp[ \dfrac{V_k}{1- \rho}])^{1-\rho} + \sum_{i=K+1}^N \exp[V_i] \Big)$$

I want to verify this numerically to make sure I am coding this second expectation correctly. However, I do not know what the cdf is for a case where draws of $\epsilon_i, ... , \epsilon_K$ are correlated with parameter $\rho$.

Thanks!